# Google Colab - Repeat Runtime Disconnect

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've tried to look through Stack Overflow for this issue and wasn't able to find any solutions to my specific situation, which is as follows (fwiw im also a python noob):

**I am using **Google Colab (Free).**

I'm trying to visualize some data (global temperature) in a radial graph, following a tutorial I found online.  Everything seemed to be going decently up until when the final animation was being produced - initially it was fine, with the exception of this warning:

> Animation size has reached 22083561 bytes, exceeding the limit of 20971520.0. If you're sure you want a larger animation embedded, set the animation.embed_limit rc parameter to a larger value (in MB). This and further frames will be dropped.

I looked up this information bit/error and found that the following code would increase the limit:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
```

From there, my sessions disconnected around the 1 minute mark after running the appropriate output code.  It takes a runtime restart and setting animation.embed_limit to 20 in order for me to get back to my semi-successful state of outputting an incomplete animation.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Code is as follows

```
# Drive Mounting
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Library Imports
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
import numpy as np

# Raw Data Import
hadcrut = pd.read_csv(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.monthly_ns_avg.txt',
    delim_whitespace=True,
    usecols=[0, 1],
    header=None)

# Data Prep
hadcrut['year'] = hadcrut.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0]).astype(int)
hadcrut['month'] = hadcrut.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[1]).astype(int)
hadcrut = hadcrut.rename(columns={1: 'value'})
hadcrut = hadcrut.iloc[:, 1:]
hadcrut = hadcrut.drop(hadcrut[hadcrut['year'] == 2018].index)
hadcrut = hadcrut.set_index(['year', 'month'])
hadcrut -= hadcrut.loc[1850:1900].mean()
hadcrut = hadcrut.reset_index()
years = hadcrut['year'].unique()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
fig.set_facecolor('#323331')

full_circle_thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
blue_line_one_radii = [1.0]*1000
red_line_one_radii = [2.5]*1000
red_line_two_radii = [3.0]*1000

ax1.plot(full_circle_thetas, blue_line_one_radii, c='blue')
ax1.plot(full_circle_thetas, red_line_one_radii, c='red')
ax1.plot(full_circle_thetas, red_line_two_radii, c='red')

ax1.text(np.pi/2, 1.0, '0.0 C', color='blue', ha='center', fontdict={'fontsize': 20})
ax1.text(np.pi/2, 2.5, '1.5 C', color='red', ha='center', fontdict={'fontsize': 20})
ax1.text(np.pi/2, 3.0, '2.0 C', color='red', ha='center', fontdict={'fontsize': 20})


def update(i):
    year = years[i]
    r = hadcrut[hadcrut['year'] == year]['value'] + 1

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 12)
    ax1.grid(False)
    ax1.set_title('Global Temperature Change (1850-2017)', color='white', fontdict={'fontsize': 20})

    ax1.set_ylim(0, 3.25)
    ax1.set_facecolor('#000100')   
    ax1.plot(theta, r, c=plt.cm.viridis(i*2))
    return ax1

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(years), interval = 50, repeat_delay = 1000)

anim
```

And here is the runtime log from restart to disconnect

> Timestamp,Level,Message
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:40 PM",INFO,Discarding 3 buffered messages for d5ff7869-edb3-4e31-a38e-20e2c655f7d2:c7df80dc0b1b4ae7959d1ea88b633edb
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:40 PM",INFO,Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel d5ff7869-edb3-4e31-a38e-20e2c655f7d2
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,    raise WebSocketClosedError()
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,"  File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py"", line 876, in wrapper"
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,"  File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py"", line 1141, in run"
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,Traceback (most recent call last):
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,    value = future.result()
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,"  File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py"", line 1133, in run"
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,    yield fut
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,"  File ""/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py"", line 874, in wrapper"
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,Traceback (most recent call last):
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,future: 
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",WARNING,ERROR:asyncio:Future exception was never retrieved
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:18:38 PM",INFO,Starting buffering for d5ff7869-edb3-4e31-a38e-20e2c655f7d2:c7df80dc0b1b4ae7959d1ea88b633edb
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:16:35 PM",INFO,Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel d5ff7869-edb3-4e31-a38e-20e2c655f7d2
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:16:33 PM",INFO,Kernel started: d5ff7869-edb3-4e31-a38e-20e2c655f7d2
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,http://172.28.0.12:9000/
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,0 active kernels
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Serving notebooks from local directory: /
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,http://172.28.0.2:9000/
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,0 active kernels
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,google.colab serverextension initialized.
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Serving notebooks from local directory: /
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,google.colab serverextension initialized.
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /root/.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /root/.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.d/panel-client-jupyter.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.d/panel-client-jupyter.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,     /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '/content' instead of '""/content""' if you require traitlets >=5."
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '/' instead of '""/""' if you require traitlets >=5."
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '172.28.0.12' instead of '""172.28.0.12""' if you require traitlets >=5."
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",INFO,Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '/content' instead of '""/content""' if you require traitlets >=5."
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '/' instead of '""/""' if you require traitlets >=5."
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,  FutureWarning)
> "Apr 16, 2022, 4:13:35 PM",WARNING,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2205: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use '172.28.0.2' instead of '""172.28.0.2""' if you require traitlets >=5."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the "free" version will be limited.

Comment: That was my fear :(  I couldn't find anything about a data limit and thought it might be readily adjustable to a reasonable degree, but I guess that might not be the case.

Comment: the limits for the "free" version (especially with a company like google) will be very onerous.  This is the official colab page: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

Comment: I created the sample data appropriately and ran it in the Colab environment. I observed the same problem as you did, so I made some changes and the animation played without error. Changes: reduced graph size, modified the number of lines to 100, and changed runtime to GPU. I don't know the details, but my guess is that you were running out of drawing resources and the GPU change solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Your code seems to be working but I can't seem to replicate success on my side, including making the adjustments you've mentioned.

The data I used is publicly available [here](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/time_series/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.monthly_ns_avg.txt), if you might be interested in trying to replicate the issue further.

Comment: @r-beginners I continued to adjust my code a bit more, and it seems like reducing the image size even further allowed me to run the full process without any errors.  Thank you for your help and suggestion!!

Comment: Why don't you self-answer your case for SO users? I think I am a very good case study

Comment: I am quite new to stack overflow as well - didn't realize it as an option, nor an etiquette, but definitely makes sense.  I will do that now.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @r-beginners I was able to somewhat resolve this issue by reducing the image size (fig) down to about (8,8), which allowed me to render it entirely without errors.

Previously:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
```

After:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
```

Honestly, given how simple the graphic was, I didn't think the process would've hit a resource wall.  However, there might be much more involved than I thought in the calculation and creation of the graphic, and just might be my naivety sustained.

Still, hope this helps someone else!

***tl;dr*** - output file size too big, assume limit with Google Colab (free version), reduce output file size, success